# How to pass the data from useSelector to useState to prevent re render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to pass the data from redux to useState but this cause multiple re-renders. It is another variant to do it?

**This is my current variant that I`m using**

```
export default function Test(){
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const currentData= useSelector(state => state.currentData);
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
 
 React.useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getData());
 },[dispatch]);

 React.useEffect(() => {
  setValue(currentData.item);
 },[data])

 return (
   <Autocomplete
    options={data}
    value={value}
   />
 )
}
```

Thanks! And sorry for my English

Comment: Why would you even keep a copy of your store value in your local state?
They're functionally equivalent, just use the store one.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store the new value coming from the store without second render, you can just use `useRef`, in case you need to keep and read that value in an event handler, let's say.

If you only need the `currentData.item` part just for the current render, I don't see a reason to use any hooks, but just normal JS variable or directly pass `currentData.item` to your dependent components. Here's how it may look like with `useRef`.

```
export default function Test(){
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const currentData= useSelector(state => state.currentData);
 const value = React.useRef(null);
 value.current = currentData.item;
 
 React.useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getData());
 },[dispatch]);

 return (
   <Autocomplete
    options={data}
    value={value.current}
   />
 )
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on the sandbox provided, I created a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-mestorf-r6rvg). Note that I removed `React.StrictMode` in index.js. This doubles the number of renders **in development only (by design)**. I also merged the country and location into a single state object, so now calling `setState` will cause 1 additional render instead of 2 as before. In total 2 renders on init - first, the usual one and second because of setting state in the effect.

Comment: The reason why I'm using hooks is because if I change the value of Autocomplete I need to store it somewhere before I do submit

Comment: Assuming *I need to store it somewhere before I do submit* means using it in some event handler, you can use the ```useRef``` approach in this case.

Comment: Maybe it's better to share a small codesandbox reproducing the issue.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-monad-v7t2w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: So you want to run the effect whenever ```profile``` changes and you don't want to have multiple renders after its execution?

Comment: The problem is that I want to have less renders. În the example that I gave you I have 5+ renders : x2 getProfile, x1 pass  profile to useState etc  I want to find a solution to remove the useEffect that pass data to useState .That useEffect fill the autocomplete with current data. I tried many things but doesn t work